# L1 and L2 Penalties on Sklearn Logistic Classifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, lasso-regression

I was looking at the scikit-learn logistic regression documentation, and saw that the penalty can be L1 and L2. I know that lasso and ridge regression are also known as L1 and L2 regularization respectively, so I was wondering if the L1 and L2 penalties refer to the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that's correct. For L1 and L2 regularization (Lasso and Ridge Regression), the regularization term is often called L1 penalty or L2 penalty.